# ArgumentError in Chapter 7 of "Rails Tutorial" by Michael Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

everyone. I've got the following problem:
After implementing has_password? in section 7.2.3 RSpec displays the following error for "should create a new instance given valid attributes" test for example

> 1) User should create a new instance given valid attributes
>        Failure/Error: User.create!(@attr)
>        ArgumentError:
>          wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
>        # ./app/models/user.rb:42:in `secure_hash'
>        # ./app/models/user.rb:39:in`make_salt'
>        # ./app/models/user.rb:30:in `encrypt_password'
>        # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:14:in`block (2 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 1.47 seconds
>   1 example, 1 failure
>     <-- Slave(1) run done!

I don't understand, what exactly causes the problem.
Here is my user.rb code:

```
    require 'digest'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name,  :presence => true,
                    :length   => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :email, :presence => true,
                     :format   => { :with => email_regex },
                     :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  # Automatically create the virtual attribute "password_confirmation"
  validates :password, :presence => true,
                    :confirmation => true,
                    :length => { :within => 6..40 } 

  before_save :encrypt_password

  # Return 'true' if the user's password matches the submitted password
  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  private

  def encrypt_password
    self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
  end

  def encrypt(string)
    secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
  end

  def make_salt
    secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
  end

  def secure_hash
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
  end
end
```

What can it be?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **secure_hash** method needs to take an argument.

```
def secure_hash(string)
  Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
end
```